# Random variable generator in Matlab running in cluster environment

Tags: matlab, random, cluster-computing

I would like to generate "truly" random variables in matlab, which is running in a cluster environment. The problem is that the random variables in matlab are being retrieved from a matrix, starting from a specific position (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).

Every time that I start executing a program in matlab, the random values are always the same. To overcome this problem, the command rng('shuffle') could be used in order to start from a random position of the matrix (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/why-do-random-numbers-repeat-after-startup.html).

However, even this command will give me the same results because the outcome of the 'shuffle' command (which is not clarified how it works) is always the same in cluster.

Any recommendation on how I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming this is an issue because you are using multiple parallel processes that have the same 'random' input. Make sure you use `rng('shuffle')` in each of the processes at a different time (the time difference can be a matter of milliseconds). `shuffle` uses the current time as an input, with quite a high resolution as shown in the following example:

```
rng('shuffle');rng
rng('shuffle');rng

rng(now);rng
rng(now);rng
```

The above code sets the random seed and immediately displays the state of the random number generator, along with its seed. The output is as follows:

```
ans = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 587753634
    State: [625x1 uint32]


ans = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 587753635
    State: [625x1 uint32]


ans = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 736028
    State: [625x1 uint32]


ans = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 736028
    State: [625x1 uint32]
```

As you can see, the `shuffle` input yields two different seeds where the `now` input apparently does not have a high enough resolution to generate new seeds this quickly.

Comment: I am not using multiple cores but matlab parallelizes some of the tasks by default. So I am using only one rng('shuffle') in the beginning of my code but the output of shuffle is always the same. As I commented in the other answer, it seems like the date in the cluster computer is resetting every time that I initialise my code.

Comment: That is quite peculiar. Perhaps you could try `rng(cputime)` to set the random seed? That will use the time MATLAB has been in use on the CPU as a seed, which is likely to not be the same number everytime you run your code.

Comment: Based on the proposals here, I believe that the problem is not in matlab but in the cluster itself. Maybe I will delete my question to avoid confusing other users.

Comment: That might be a good idea. However, I recommend re-asking the question with the cluster specifics (i.e. is it likely that more people may encounter this problem). A resetting system clock when running MATLAB is definitely strange behaviour in my book, so if you find anything interesting in that regard it might be worthwhile sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you feed a starting "seed" to a random number generator, a good source is the current time, so you can try something like

```
 rng(now)
```

See for instance [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/07/07/simpler-control-of-random-number-generation-in-matlab/) for more examples.

Note: I have not tested this myself!

Comment: I also tried this one but it doesn't work. It seems like the date in the cluster computer is resetting every time that I initialise my code. Thank anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Why not seed the random number generator using genuinely random numbers from random.org, using this http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27942-www-random-org-random-integers-sequences-strings

Answer (score 0):

`rng('shuffle')` seeds the random number generator based on the current time, so I'm not sure why you are getting the same results everytime.

Anyway, you shouldn't use `rng('shuffle')` to set the random number seed on each worker if you want to assure that each worker has different seeds.

So, basically you need to do the `rng('shuffle')` globally and not inside each worker.

This will give you different values everytime, on each worker:

```
rng('shuffle')
spmd
R = rand(1,4); % Different on each worker
end
```

This will give you the same value everytime, on all workers, because all workers will be initialized at the same time with the same rng seed.

```
spmd
rng('shuffle')
R = rand(1,4); % Equal on each worker
end
```